# Upgrading a system with /home on a different physical drive

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, home-directory

I plan to set up my computer so that the operating system is on an SSD, while the /home directory is on an HDD.  I know how to install Ubuntu so that the system will be as I want it to be.  When I eventually upgrade the operating system (say from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04), is there a way to just update the operating system without overwriting the /home directory?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1160269/edit) your question and indicate how you plan to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04. Will you use a Live USB of 20.04 ISO and install the 20.04 version over the 19.04 version? Or will you use the GUI **Software Updates** tool or the command line tools to update from 19.10 to 20.04?

Comment: I did not think of including how I would upgrade - most likely via ISO.  I will try to be clearer in my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your /home directory as long as data is concerned will not be affected by system upgrades.

So you can unmount it from one system and mount it on another system and still be able to access your data as it was before.

However applications configuration files which reside in your `/home` directory (eg. Firefox, LibreOffice ...etc) can be affected during system upgrades.

Fortunately these configuration files can be backed up and restored when needed.

So, **short answer** is your configuration will work as you intend it to be and you can do system upgrades later.

Piece of advice:
system is almost always fixable, but data is not. So please keep data backups always.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  And I ALWAYS keep a backup after having been burned many years ago.